# Since $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin kx}{kx}=1$ for constants $k$, is it also true for general arguments?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

To be more specific, is it true that
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin f(x)}{f(x)}=1~~?$$
I'm tempted to say yes at first glance, so long as $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to0$.

The reason I ask is to verify this limit result:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{\sin r^2}{r^2}$$
where I changed variables to polar coordinates via $r^2=x^2+y^2$. It would be nice to know whether I can make this sort of generalization.

Comment: sine should cosine @CameronWilliams

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable, l'Hospital's rule would give that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin f(x)}{f(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)\cos f(x)}{f'(x)} = \cos f(0) = 1.$$ For your purposes, this is a differentiable function so it works as expected. This assumes that $f'$ isn't zero in some neighborhood of $0$ though. If that is not the case, you might have to keep repeating the process.

Comment: @CameronWilliams +1 for the insightful comment!

Comment: Yes, if $f(x)$ has limit $0$ then $\frac{\sin(f(x))}{f(x)}$ has limit $1$.

Comment: I just realized I had forgotten about the squeeze theorem... I wonder if there's a case where it doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as there is some neighborhood $U$ of $0$ so that $f(x) \ne 0$ for all $x \in U\setminus\{0\}$, this is correct - and this assumption just needs to be made so the limit is well-defined.

You can see this directly from the definition of the limit. It is pretty easy if you work with sequences. Let $x_n$ be an arbitrary sequence so that $x_n \to 0$. Then $y_n = f(x_n)$ is a sequence that converges to $0$ aswell. But this implies $\frac{\sin(f(x_n))}{f(x_n)} = \frac{\sin(y_n)}{y_n} \to 0$, which proves the assertion.

Answer (score 2):

For any $x$,
$$\sin x = x + \frac{\cos(\zeta_x)\cdot x^3}{3!},$$
for some $\zeta_x$ between 0 and $x$. Then
$$\frac{\sin f(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{f(x) + \frac{\cos(\eta_x)\cdot f(x)^3}{3!}}{f(x)} = 1 + \frac{\cos(\eta_x)\cdot f(x)^2}{3!}$$
for some $\eta_x$ between 0 and $f(x)$. As $x \to 0$, $f(x) \to 0$ and $\eta_x \to 0$, so the limit is 1. This does not require $f$ to be differentiable anywhere or $f(0)$ to exist.